# Is $x^4 + 4$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Well, I'm having doubts, isnt that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ has no zero divisors, and now you cant factor  $x^4 + 4$ ?

Comment: Just plug in any number...

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
x^4+4&=x^4-1\\
&=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)\\
&=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2-4)\\
&=(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)(x-2)\\
&=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4).
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Note that $x^4+4$ is not irreducible over **any** field, since
$$x^4+4=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2).$$

Answer (score 3):

Obviously $x-1$ is a factor since $1^4+4=0$.

Comment: Also, you're working in $\mathbb{Z}_5[X]$, not $\mathbb{5}_5$.

Answer (score 0):

You've already been answered, but observe it is easier than it appears on this case since $\;4=-1\pmod 5\;$ , so doing arithmetic modulo $\;5\;$ all along we get

$$x^4+4=x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)$$

The last step follows easily if we know that $\;-1\;$ is a quadratic residue as $\;5=1\pmod4\;$, for example. Or else directly trying the well known formula for the roots of a quadratic.